# jQuery Slider Dropping Down To New Line

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery slider that I've created based on 6 slides. It initially opens with one slider image open at 50% and the other 5 open at 10% the width of the container (as it will be a responsive site)

I then have jQuery to make whichever item is hovered over to change to 50% width and the rest to drop to 10%, the trouble is that it drops to a new line (goes over 100%) when the mouse hovers over an item.

How can I stop this occuring? It needs to seamlessly transfer between slides and fill the entire container, my code is below and you can see the working example [**here**](http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/) with a 
**[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/BjyPH/)** here

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(".inside").mouseout(function() {  

jQuery('.inside').animate( {width: '10%'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false,  });
jQuery('#one').animate({width: '50%'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });

});

jQuery(".inside").mouseover(function() { 


jQuery(".inside").animate({width: '10%'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
jQuery(this).animate( {width: '50%'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false, });

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="slide-show-holder">

<div id="container">

<div class="inside" id="one"></div>
<div class="inside" id="two"></div>
<div class="inside" id="three"></div>
<div class="inside" id="four"></div>
<div class="inside" id="five"></div>
<div class="inside" id="six"></div>

</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* SLIDESHOW STYLES ================================================== */

#container              { width: 100%; height: 300px; cursor: pointer; margin: auto;    }
#container .inside      { width: 10%; display: inline; float: left; height: 330px; position: relative;  }
#container  #one        { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/business-loans-for-women.jpg'); width: 50%;         }
#container  #two        { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/business-man-and-woman.jpeg');  }
#container  #three      { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/303961321.jpeg');   }
#container  #four       { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/general-business-insurance.jpg');   }
#container  #five       { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/shutterstock_76925098.jpg');    }
#container  #six        { background: url('http://stafford.networkintellect4.info/wp-content/themes/stafford/images/business-plan.jpg');    }


/* END SLIDESHOW STYLES ================================================== */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only logical explanation for me is that during the animation the sum of all widths at some point equals more than 100% (rounding bugs/features) because you use %'s.
You can either specify a fixed with for the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/BjyPH/3/

or add `overflow:hidden` to the container. By the way, I don't think you need that mouseleave function. You can do it only with mouseenter:

```
jQuery(".inside").mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "50%"
    }, 500);
    $(this).siblings().stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "10%"
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BjyPH/2/

This is probably the better solution although there is still some flickering at the last slide because of the animation using `%` (see above).

Edit: or you can use jQuery 1.7.2 :D

http://jsfiddle.net/BjyPH/4/

Comment: Hi Kaloyan, thanks for the response. It appears to be to do with animate on the percentage widths as you said, if I dont use animate then it works as expected... You say jQuery 1.7.2, why would this work?

Comment: Seems like 1.8.3 is a bit too buggy.

Answer (score 0):

change this (change width: 90%; in #container )

```
#container {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

i seen it has been solved in mozilla firefox

Comment: Hi mate, it still occassionally drops to a new line and now the slideshow doesn't fill the whole container area as its now at 90%, please see the development site link

Comment: Well im testing in Firefox but I've opened it up in IE and Chrome and the same problem occurs